# VS For Mac Multiplatform Project References

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I am in the process of reworking a .Net Windows app in VS for Mac since I no longer have a PC.  I want to have two projects: a Mac specific UI project and a multiplatform Core project.  I can't figure out what kind of project I need to add to get Core working properly.

My logic uses a DataTable, and I can add the System.Data reference to my Mac UI project, however, I need it in the Core project instead.  Currently, I have my Core set up as a Portable Library, and the .NET Portable Subset does not include System.Data.  I would like Core to run on both Mac and Windows in case I ever get a PC again.  Since I can reference System.Data in the Mac UI project I would think there is a way to do this in Core.  Is there a way, or do I need to use a data structure other than DataTable to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.DataTable` exists in `NetStandard` 2.0, so add a `NetStandard` 2.0 library to your solution and add that library as a project reference to your Xamarin.Mac project.